# How to ignore a JsonProperty just for a given single endPoint and let it works for others

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have two endPoints that returns this Json :

```
 "type": {
      "nbrCurrentRemainingDays": 0,
      "desc": "put desc here !",
      "id": 32
    }
```

I need to make it ignore the desc for the first endPoint and let it for the second , is there any solution other than creating another ResponseDTO ?
`@jsonIgnore` will ignore the property for all endPoints.

---

For the first endPoint : no desc

```
 "type": {
      "nbrCurrentRemainingDays": 0,
      "id": 32
    }
```

For the second : with desc

```
"type": {
      "nbrCurrentRemainingDays": 0,
      "desc": "put desc here !",
      "id": 32
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` should do the trick.

Include.NON_EMPTY: Indicates that only properties that are not empty will be included in JSON.

### The simplest solution,

**Root.java**

```
public class Root {
    public Type type;
    //Todo getter setter constructor
}
```

**Type.java**

```
public class Type {

    public int nbrCurrentRemainingDays;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    public String desc;
    public int id;

//Todo getter setter constructor
}
```

**MyController.java**

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/all-fields")
    public Root test1() {

        Root root = new Root();
        Type type = new Type();
        type.setNbrCurrentRemainingDays(0);
        type.setId(32);
        type.setDesc("put desc here !");
        root.setType(type);
        return root;
    }

    @GetMapping("/ignore-desc")
    public Root test2() {

        Root root = new Root();
        Type type = new Type();
        type.setNbrCurrentRemainingDays(0);
        type.setId(32);
        type.setDesc("put desc here !");
        root.setType(type);

        //Set null value 
        type.setDesc(null);
        return root;
    }
}
```

**Endpoint 1:localhost:8080/all-fields(with desc)**

```
  {
    "type": {
        "nbrCurrentRemainingDays": 0,
        "desc": "put desc here !",
        "id": 32
    }
}
```

**Endpoint 2: localhost:8080/ignore-desc(no desc)**

```
  {
    "type": {
        "nbrCurrentRemainingDays": 0,
        "id": 32
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know `desc` is empty for both end point?

Comment: He is sure the desc field must be ignored on the first endpoint, so the desc is always empty on the first endpoint. So desc = null. He is finding a solution with minimum code changes.

Comment: @Sibin thanks for your answer , the field may be not null

Answer (score 0):

use @JsonIgnore annotation for the field and create a manual getter and setter for the desc field where the setter will be returned based on the field value.

The setter, Getter method needs to be annotated with @JsonProperty, Now setter will return the value based on the URL path (or any condition based on your choice).

Comment: thanks for the answer , a small correction ; getter will return the value and not setter , i want to combine your solution with the one writen by Sibin and see the result .

Answer (score 0):

I know a solution for this. You can extend the Json Serializer class and override the serialize method in it. You can disable the fields you don't want in it.
just like this

[JsonView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg9Hn.png)

Comment: Please share any relevant code in the Question, as a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not all users will click on links and therefore won't be able to help reproduce, and solve, your issue.